# Display on-hover event on UI-Grid

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, onhover

I use http://ui-grid.info/ as below:

```
<div ncy-breadcrumb class="title-shadow"></div>
    {{ getDeviceTree }}

<div>
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-selection></div>
</div>
```

and my goal is to have http://plnkr.co/edit/gKqt8JEo2FukS3URRLJ5?p=preview

[image]

Thanks a lot for any hints and/or recommendations of different than UI-grid component.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem? Can you create another plnkr with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily ui-grid provides GridOptions for configuring these options. The closest I could get to is this.

**in your app.js**

```
myApp.config(function($provide){
      $provide.decorator('GridOptions',function($delegate){
        var gridOptions;
        gridOptions = angular.copy($delegate);
        gridOptions.initialize = function(options) {
          var initOptions;
          initOptions = $delegate.initialize(options);
          initOptions.rowTemplate = '<div ng-click="grid.appScope.fnOne(row)" ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell mouseover" ui-grid-cell></div>';
          return initOptions;
        };
        return gridOptions;
      });
    });
```

**and then in your css**

```
.mouseover :hover
{
    background: red;
}
```